# Adding a list box item after the data binding of listbox is complete in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to Add a listbox item after the listbox data binding is complete so that the item which i am inserting always is at the last position....

Comment: They are at the last position by default.

Comment: I think you can add your item into the binding list first. and then bind the new list to your listbox.

Comment: What is itemsource ? list or Observable collection ?

Comment: its done......i just converted the ienumerable list to list<string> and the called the ADD() function of list..and then set the binding source to that new list i created